# how to understand a linker error

Tags: gcc, ld, elf

I'm trying to compile a dynamic library with an exotic mix of versions.
First I'm cross-compiling  for a ADM geode inside a robot, with a particular toolchain that uses gcc-4.3.3, and has its own directory tree for finds its headers and link libs, but i'm using a lot of numeric libraries such boost::numeric, blas, and a robot dynamic and kininematic model library named jrl-dynamics, thats sends linker errors.

When I compile, first, all object files are generated without problems (because I hack the toolchain include making symbolic links), but at linking time I got errors like:

```
/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf.0: undefined reference to `_gfortran_string_len_trim@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf.0: undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string@GFORTRAN_1.0'
```

and

```
/usr/lib/libjrl-dynamics.so.1.19.3-42-g8c6f: undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'
```

I wish to force the linker to find the symbols like _gfortran_string_len_trim y my
requested version of gfortran that is gfortran2, where in fact with reafelf command i found all the simbols requested by lapack. but the -L/mypath/gfortran2 does not work!! and i got the same errors. 
I want to know what means that @ in the linker errors, where the elf files says the linker to searh the symbos???.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `@` in symbols are related to [versionning](http://sca.uwaterloo.ca/coldfire/gcc-doc/docs/ld_25.html), but I am not very familiar with that. See also [dlvsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlvsym)